# PL/SQL ERROR: Encountered the Symbol "INSERT"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I'm trying to do a simple program, but I'm getting an error on my Insert and I have no idea why. I've already created my sequence and table(Lab1_tab) but have not included them here. Enrollment and Student tables are both working fine. My error is on the first Insert at line 18. The exact error is PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

```
DECLARE
v_lname VARCHAR(20);
v_id NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
  SELECT s.last_name
  INTO v_lname
  FROM enrollment e, student s
  WHERE e.student_id = s.student_id
  AND LENGTH(s.last_name) < 9
  GROUP BY s.last_name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT MAX(count(student_id))
            FROM enrollment
            GROUP BY student_id);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
END;
INSERT INTO Lab1_tab                        //ERROR
   VALUES(LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);
BEGIN
      SELECT s.last_name
      INTO v_lname
      FROM enrollment e, student s
      WHERE e.student_id = s.student_id
      AND LENGTH(s.last_name) < 9
      GROUP BY s.last_name
      having count(*) = ( SELECT MIN(count(student_id))
                        FROM enrollment
                        GROUP BY student_id);
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
    END;
    INSERT INTO Lab1_tab
       VALUES (LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);
BEGIN
      SELECT i.last_name
      INTO v_lname
      FROM instructor i, section s
      WHERE s.instructor_id = i.instructor_id
      AND i.last_name NOT LIKE '%s'
      GROUP BY i.last_name
      having count(*) = ( SELECT MIN(count(*))
                        FROM section
                        GROUP BY instructor_id );
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
    END;
    INSERT INTO Lab1_tab
      VALUES (1, v_lname); 
BEGIN
    SELECT i.last_name
    INTO v_lname
    FROM instructor i, section s
    WHERE s.instructor_id = i.instructor_id
    AND i.last_name NOT LIKE '%s'
    GROUP BY i.last_name
    having count(*) = ( SELECT MAX(count(*))
                        FROM section
                        GROUP BY instructor_id );
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
END;
INSERT INTO Lab1_tab
    VALUES (LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);  
END;
/
```

Comment: try specifying the columns inside the insert. e.g `INSERT INTO Lab1_tab (value, lastName)
       VALUES (LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);`

Comment: Just tried and same Error occurs

Comment: Try putting your INSERT inside the `BEGIN` / `END`

Comment: dustyrush is right, moreover the issue is due to missing an extra `BEGIN` after `BEGIN` at line 4.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, that you are trying to execute a PL/SQL anonymous block, but have closed the block to soon. I.e. the first `END`, you probably intended to just close the "try-catch" block, actually closed the whole thing.
Maybe you got confused by the `DECLARE`, which is starting the anonymous block, but is **not** starting a code block - you still have to have `BEGIN` for it.
Try something like this:

```
DECLARE
  v_lname VARCHAR(20);
  v_id NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT s.last_name
    INTO v_lname
    FROM enrollment e, student s
    WHERE e.student_id = s.student_id
    AND LENGTH(s.last_name) < 9
    GROUP BY s.last_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT MAX(count(student_id))
              FROM enrollment
              GROUP BY student_id);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
  END;

  INSERT INTO Lab1_tab                        //ERROR
     VALUES(LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);

  BEGIN
    SELECT s.last_name
    INTO v_lname
    FROM enrollment e, student s
    WHERE e.student_id = s.student_id
    AND LENGTH(s.last_name) < 9
    GROUP BY s.last_name
    having count(*) = ( SELECT MIN(count(student_id))
                        FROM enrollment
                        GROUP BY student_id);
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
  END;

  INSERT INTO Lab1_tab
     VALUES (LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);

  BEGIN
    SELECT i.last_name
    INTO v_lname
    FROM instructor i, section s
    WHERE s.instructor_id = i.instructor_id
    AND i.last_name NOT LIKE '%s'
    GROUP BY i.last_name
    having count(*) = ( SELECT MIN(count(*))
                        FROM section
                        GROUP BY instructor_id );
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
  END;

  INSERT INTO Lab1_tab
    VALUES (1, v_lname); 

  BEGIN
    SELECT i.last_name
    INTO v_lname
    FROM instructor i, section s
    WHERE s.instructor_id = i.instructor_id
    AND i.last_name NOT LIKE '%s'
    GROUP BY i.last_name
    having count(*) = ( SELECT MAX(count(*))
                        FROM section
                        GROUP BY instructor_id );
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      v_lname := 'Multiple Names';
  END;

  INSERT INTO Lab1_tab
    VALUES (LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);  

END;
/
```

**Edit**:
All in all, when in doubt, count your `BEGIN`s and `END`s and see if the numbers match. :)

Comment: adding an explanation might be nice for `INSERT INTO Lab1_tab  VALUES(LAB1_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_lname);` that "the insert statement works properly if Lab1_tab has two columns exactly with the compatible data types with the arguments in the values list, respectively".

Answer (score 0):

After PL/SQL anonymous blocks, there needs to be a `/` character to allow DDL statements to run.

Comment: Not exactly true. This is just a client side (application) block separator. It's traditionally used with Oracle DB clients, as it was something that Oracle's SQL*Plus used as a default PL/SQL separator. It was a way to tell the SQL*Plus, that you've finished your PL/SQL, so it sends the code to the Oracle DB **without** the slash character.

Comment: You are technically correct. The best kind of correct. Thanks for the clarity!